# Java prints numbers instead of the letter 'x'

Tags: java

I'm trying to show an array of numbers, but showing me 'X' instead of number:

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Arraypruebaz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] numeros = new int[10][10];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char car = 'x';
        for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("");
            for (j = 0; j < numeros[0].length; j++) {
               numeros[i][j] = car;
                System.out.print(numeros[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's because `numeros[i][j]` is an `int`. Print `car` instead.

Comment: You have a random variable but you don't use it for anything, instead you print a variable with x

Comment: Leaning what a debugger is would do you good and save us time.

Comment: Your question title and body say opposite things.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `int` array to store `'x'`, hence when you print it, it gives you the [UTF-16 code unit value](https://ascii.cl/) value of `'x'` which is `120`.

To see `'x'`, either use char array:

```
char [][] numeros = new char[10][10];
```

Or cast value to `char` as it prints:

```
System.out.print( (char)numeros[i][j] + " ");
```

Comment: Not ASCII value; UTF-16 code unit value. Java's [text datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) use the [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set (as do VB4, VBA, .NET, JavaScript, SQL NCHAR and NVARCHAR, Win32 API, NTFS, …).